# GeoServer configuration for a new user

Tags: geoserver, configuration

My main purpose is creating a set of users with specific roles.

I'm running GeoServer 2.13.

On the first step I wanted to create a role with access to one workspace - "UNIVERSITY"

So I've created:

- A new user "test_student" in Default XML user/group service.
- A new role "STUDENT" without parents.
- A rule for the "STUDENT" role with a permission to write all layers and groups in workspace "UNIVERSITY".

[image: created permissions for read and write]

Then I logged in the GeoServer account under the new user (test_student) and got nothing:

[image]

But I expected to get all layers in specified workspace. By the way when I set "ADMIN" as a parent for my role "STUDENT" I got all data without any restrictions.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to have read access to see a layer

Comment: @IanTurton Unfortunately, It doesn't help me. I've created 2 rules (divided "read" and "write"): "UNIVERSITY.*.r", "UNIVERSITY.*.w" and got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Due to solve the problem it needs to switch on the catalog mode to MIXED or CHALLENGE (default state is HIDE).

So, we get the "HIDE" catalog mode doesn't show us geoserver sections (workspaces, stores, layers etc) but other modes allow us to see all sections on the left bar and layers inside.

[image]

Available layers:

[image]